# Compactitem in tabular produces extra vertical space after environment

Tags: spacing, tabularx, paralist

If I use compactitem in a tabular(x), there is a vertical space before and after the listing environment. How can I remove that space?

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{paralist, tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{compactitem}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\end{compactitem}
    There is no verstical space after the compactitem-environment.



\bigskip
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l X}
\hline
a & b\\
a &     \begin{compactitem}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\end{compactitem}\\
a& \dots but in the tabular, there \emph{is} vertical space after and before the einvironment!\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{paralist, tabularx}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\@minipagetrue}p{#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l X}\hline
a & b\\
a &     \begin{compactitem}
\item Item 1
\item Item 2
\end{compactitem}\\[-\normalbaselineskip]
a& \dots but in the tabular, there \emph{is} vertical space after and before the einvironment!\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]